# signalR 401 error ($.connection.hub.start())

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr

i tried to connect to hub with signalR in my page:

```
            $(function() {
            var rateHubProxy = $.connection.rateHub;
            //...
            $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8081/signalr';
            $.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function () {
                console.log('We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.')
            });
            $.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
                console.log('SignalR error: ' + error)
            });
            $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id); })
                .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not Connect!'); });
        });
```

but i have 401 in `$.connection.hub.start()`. RateHub have Authorize attribute. 
startup config in my app:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieName = ".AuctionWebAuth",
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
        };
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
        app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration() {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            EnableJSONP = true
        });
        GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new SignalRUserIdProvider());            
    }
```

How do I get authorization?